# Best solution for a networking background task

Tags: android, android-background

We are developing an app that is:

- Collecting data in the background
- Uploading the data every few hours

We are facing a problem with a background task that run at a regular interval to upload the data to our back-end server.

The problem is when running on our test devices (Nexus 5x , Galaxy S7) it uploads the data just fine, but on our released version, there are about 40% of users who haven’t uploading the data to our server within a day. We are using Firebase Analytic with event logging to verify if our method is working or not.

We are using job scheduling methods because we can’t use a background service anymore on Android 8 (background service limitation).

On our latest version we are using Android JobScheduler job for our networking background task.

Here’s the example of our code:

```
// Schedule JobScheduler job
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, UploadJobService.class);
JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceComponent)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build();
JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
mJobScheduler.schedule(job);
```

The stats from Firebase Analytic showed that the job is never getting started (onStartJob is not getting called) on 40% of users within a day.

We are taking into consideration that the users device may not have internet connection and the device can go into doze mode or app is on App standby mode.

We want to know if there is anything wrong with our solution and if there are any better solution for our use case. We want the app to correctly send the data that we collected within a day.

Comment: This might help you! https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

Answer (score 1):

Framework Job Scheduler targets API level 21. And If the device is less than API level 21 job will not be triggered.

Please go through link job scheduling in app for better performance .

[Intelligent Job Scheduling](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#af)

Firebase JobDispatcher supports the use of Google Play services as an implementation for dispatching (running) jobs, but the library also allows you to define and use other implementations: For example, you might decide to use JobScheduler or write your own, custom code. Because of this versatility, we recommend that you use this Firebase JobDispatcher if your app targets a version of Android lower than 5.0 (API level 21).